# Serverless Lambda function doesn't map to response correctly

Tags: aws-lambda, httpresponse, serverless

I have a problem with correcltly returning the response of a Lambda function that I deploy using the Serverless framework:

```
module.exports.hello = async (event, context, callback) => {

  const content = fs.readFileSync('./cn23_template.html', 'utf-8')

  const Vue = require('vue')
  const app = new Vue({
    template: content,
    data: function () {
      return event
    }
  })

  const renderer = require('vue-server-renderer').createRenderer()
  const html = await renderer.renderToString(app)

  const browser = await chromium.puppeteer.launch({
    // Required
    executablePath: await chromium.executablePath,

    // Optional
    args: chromium.args,
    defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
    headless: chromium.headless || true
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setContent(html);
  let pdf = await page.pdf({ pageRanges: '1', format: 'a4', printBackground: true });

  await browser.close();

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
      'Content-Length': pdf.length
    },
    body: pdf ? pdf.toString('base64') : null,
    isBase64Encoded: true
  }
}
```

My `serverless.yml` file:

```
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http:
          path: hello
          method: post
          integration: lambda
          response:
            headers:
              Content-Type: "'Test'"
              Cache-Control: "'max-age=120'"
```

The problem is that what I return from the function is not correctly mapped to the response. The response doesn't include the `statusCode` and `headers`, it just uses the whole returned object as body of the response.

Besides this, the headers as configured in the .yml are also not being used.

It seems like a very silly mistake, but I'm just doing exactly what is inside the [Serverless API gateway docs](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#api-gateway).

So my question is: How do I properly configure the response properties so that the HTTP request gives the correct response using the Serverless framework?

Comment: I believe you need to have integration configuration as `lambda-proxy`, not lambda.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your lambda function to be invoked as a lambda-proxy event.

See [Serverless Example Lambda Proxy](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#example-lambda-proxy-event-default)